# Repeat Content with different NG-Includes - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have two divs on a page, outer and inner. The outer one has same styling everywhere on the page, so I would like to repeat it using ng-repeat (what actually works fine). The inner one should contain different content, which I would like to insert from different html templates using ng-include directive. The code I wrote does not show me any error messages, however does not work. Could you please see what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller="myCtrl as ctrl">

<div id="outer" ng-repeat="tpl in ctrl.templates">
    <div id="inner" ng-include="tpl.templates">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
       .controller('myCtrl', [function() {
        var self = this;
        self.templates = [
            {template: 'template.htm'},
            {template: 'template2.htm'},
            {template: 'template3.htm'},
            {template: 'template4.htm'}
        ]
    }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know if it is right but i guess there is an error in

```
ng-include="tpl.templates"
```

I think it should be :

```
ng-include="tpl.template"
```

(removed "s" from templates)

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what I didn't notice! thanks! :)